# Android AWS DynamoDB "No hash key condition"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table that has some data. There is a hashkey of "class_id" and a rangekey of "message_timestamp".

In my android code I am attempting to query for messages that are newer than the last message received.

```
int lastMessageTimestamp = GetNewestTimestamp();

DynamoChatData messagesToFind = new DynamoChatData();
Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(class_id));
messagesToFind.SetClassId(class_id); // Set to 2 in the debugger at runtime

Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition();
rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GT.toString());

AttributeValue attributeValue = new AttributeValue();
attributeValue.withN(String.valueOf(lastMessageTimestamp));

rangeKeyCondition.withAttributeValueList(attributeValue);

DynamoDBQueryExpression<DynamoChatData> query = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<>();
query.withHashKeyValues(messagesToFind);
query.withRangeKeyCondition("message_timestamp", rangeKeyCondition);
query.withConsistentRead(false);

PaginatedQueryList result = objectMapper.query(DynamoChatData.class, query);
```

The DynamoChatData class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "scriyb_chat")
public class DynamoChatData {
    private int class_id;
    private int message_timestamp;
    private String user_name;
    private String user_full_name;
    private String message_content;
    private int message_visible;
    private int message_underage;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "message_timestamp")
    public int GetMessageTimestamp(){
        return message_timestamp;
    }

    public void SetMessageTimestamp(int _message_timestamp){
        message_timestamp = _message_timestamp;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "class_id")
    public int GetClassId(){
        return class_id;
    }

    public void SetClassId(int _class_id){
        class_id = _class_id;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "user_name")
    public String GetUsername(){
        return user_name;
    }

    public void SetUsername(String _user_name){
        user_name = _user_name;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "user_full_name")
    public String GetUserFullName(){
        return user_full_name;
    }

    public void SetUserFullName(String _user_full_name){
        user_full_name = _user_full_name;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "message_content")
    public String GetMessageContent(){
        return message_content;
    }

    public void SetMessageContent(String _message_content){
        message_content = _message_content;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "message_visible")
    public int GetMessageVisible(){
        return message_visible;
    }

    public void SetMessageVisible(int _message_visible){
        message_visible = _message_visible;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "message_underage")
    public int GetMessageUnderage(){
        return message_underage;
    }

    public void SetMessageUnderage(int _message_underage){
        message_underage = _message_underage;
    }
}
```

I followed the basic example outlined [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html#define-a-mapping-class) and have read a bunch of posts on this site as well. Not sure why I get the

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is found in the query
```

error.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using refactoring your getter/setter names so that they start with a lowercase letter as is standard Java convention.  I believe the mapper looks for getters as methods that start with "get" and I think it's missing yours since they start with a capitol G.

Let me know if this resolves your problem!
Weston

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I attempted changing the casing of the functions. I am getting the same error. The debugger still says that the value is set correctly.